# join 3 queries in one

Tags: mysql

i´m traying to do create a historic from user, where in this historic we can see all data from user, and how was spent his minutes for one offer that he buyed. When user request one assistance this, it has a one or more actuation. (One assistance for computing, for example change a grafic card or remote assistance). When we are doing actuation, this subtraction minutes to offer user, ok.

My query is:

```
Select * 
FROM contratan c
RIGHT join asistencia a
ON a.usuario = c.usuario
RIGHT JOIN actuacion ac
ON a.codAsistencia = ac.asistencia
WHERE c.usuario = 17
AND c.codContrato in (select MAX(codContrato) from contratan where usuario = 17)
order by c.usuario
```

This query show all data that i need, but also i need "used time" for actuation, and time left for offer. i want to say, that if i buy a offer of 10Min and one technical aply one actuation for this offer of 2 min i have now in my offer 8 min.

and my actuation is: 2 Min. but if now i buy other offer to 30Min now i have 38min in my offer and if i apply other actuation of 15Min

i have in my offer: 23Min and my actuation time is 15. if i do now my historic:

```
offer  time in offer  hire date  date assistance  date actuation  time spent  time left
10MIn       10        2020-11-27 2020-11-20       2020-11-27      2Min         8Min
30MIn       30        2020-11-27 2020-11-20       2020-11-27      15Min        23Min
```

I need this return.

Actually i have this return:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF9AN.png)

and if i add my other two queries to calculate this:

```
Select sum(minutos) 
FROM bonos, contratan 
where contratan.bono = bonos.codBono and contratan.usuario = 17
```

and

```
Select sum(tiempoEmpleado) 
FROM actuacion, asistencia 
where actuacion.asistencia = asistencia.codAsistencia and asistencia.usuario = 17
```

my return is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQnZD.png)

i know that i have to add more data in select, but if you can see this pic, you can see all data duplicate and my time is incorrect, this time in pic it´s added for twice.

i add my database data.

**User table**

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nif` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_verified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `perfil` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'usuario',
  `telefono` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `nif`, `nombre`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `direccion`, `perfil`, `telefono`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(2, '123456', 'Admin', 'daviserraalonso@hotmail.com', NULL, '$2y$10$/BfMjo1J8W.UFtQAGTUX9O0Ae9RilA5JFipu0ZVnLWrwDSIQ65NBS', NULL, 'tecnico', NULL, NULL, '2020-11-08 07:59:29', '2020-11-08 07:59:29'),
(4, '12345678A', 'JOSE DE LA ROSA', 'delium500@gmail.com', NULL, '$2y$10$8iSFZMlM0otvX0cxATDAh.SQ/W93qVjjqTu5ir6eEL.qLaAiAVTEO', NULL, 'usuario', 958815588, NULL, '2020-11-16 06:26:10', '2020-11-16 06:26:10'),
(5, '44444A', 'ASISTENCIA', 'asistencia@eintegra.es', NULL, '$2y$10$0O99J/YBH1YPy8LyY295jeOZSEKERS03VPu0Y2ruuu7Ptihkugagu', NULL, 'tecnico', 958994057, 'hDPIg6shf2vxlDH2BmdngA45r4ZK2oDyjw3iPIYbSKPkfPPePxeyBB6viRDr', '2020-11-16 07:19:33', '2020-11-16 07:19:33'),
(6, '123456789z', 'Roberto', 'roberto@eintegra.es', NULL, '$2y$10$LfxCvBg.2bbpn0QmJPFyP.qSeauu3EgBCMvwFZWZfmbQQh4y9QS0G', NULL, 'usuario', 958815588, NULL, '2020-11-16 08:23:15', '2020-11-16 08:23:15'),
(12, '12345678A', 'Victor', 'victor.baena@integrainformatica.es', NULL, '$2y$10$xJezb.utl4nEMA6zFOfUP.cIWT1.lvh2oa6AidMEuJxugtTVKsHVq', NULL, 'usuario', 601121332, NULL, '2020-11-18 13:36:27', '2020-11-18 13:36:27'),
(13, '24279958P', 'LUIS DE LA ROSA', 'jose@eintegra.es', NULL, '$2y$10$D06AtuQs96ZfViDHARW2I.7qcvnHBiEH42LI660eacJU7e6u2ybh6', NULL, 'usuario', 649880702, NULL, '2020-11-20 14:56:19', '2020-11-20 14:56:19'),
(17, '45921676z', 'David Serrano Alonso', 'daviserraalonso@gmail.com', NULL, '$2y$10$7AD3XCKGGZ9WWFiLIwDStuYEX9khXtuFJqQphyCp0rNrnXbs504Vy', NULL, 'usuario', 652138927, NULL, '2020-11-20 18:32:51', '2020-11-20 18:32:51'),
(18, 'B18893644', 'JOSE DE LA ROSA PRUEBA 2', 'info@emseel.com', NULL, '$2y$10$QbsmX/w5kvWbOloArq26Mu0aTIQm9h5yN7gxZphOP1cpVAZNnS7ki', NULL, 'usuario', 958815588, NULL, '2020-11-24 06:44:50', '2020-11-24 06:44:50'),
(19, 'B18470468', 'AGROPECUARIOS BLASHER', 'angel@blasher.es', NULL, '$2y$10$Z99gAGnZRTRd2M72.PQMLurtdJRWNNoLtNN1vVMMmYs3xEtGCWq6i', NULL, 'usuario', 667718365, NULL, '2020-11-25 09:17:35', '2020-11-25 09:17:35');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=20;
COMMIT;
```

**Tabla contratan**

```
    CREATE TABLE `contratan` (
  `codContrato` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `bono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tiempoRestanteBono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `activo` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `contratan`
--

INSERT INTO `contratan` (`codContrato`, `fecha`, `bono`, `tiempoRestanteBono`, `activo`, `usuario`) VALUES
(8, '2020-11-26 18:48:05', 6, 8, 1, 17),
(9, '2020-11-26 20:02:16', 1, 30, 1, 17);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `contratan`
--
ALTER TABLE `contratan`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codContrato`),
  ADD KEY `contratan_usuario_foreign` (`usuario`),
  ADD KEY `contratan_bono_foreign` (`bono`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `contratan`
--
ALTER TABLE `contratan`
  MODIFY `codContrato` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=10;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `contratan`
--
ALTER TABLE `contratan`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_contratan_bono` FOREIGN KEY (`bono`) REFERENCES `bonos` (`codBono`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_contratan_usuarios` FOREIGN KEY (`usuario`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

**offer**

```
 CREATE TABLE `bonos` (
  `codBono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `minutos` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `precio` double(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `bonos`
--

INSERT INTO `bonos` (`codBono`, `tipo`, `minutos`, `precio`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, '1/2H', 30, 20.00, NULL, NULL),
(2, '1H', 60, 40.00, NULL, NULL),
(3, '5H', 300, 175.00, NULL, NULL),
(4, '10H', 600, 330.00, NULL, NULL),
(5, '24H', 1200, 600.00, NULL, NULL),
(6, '10Min', 10, 9.00, NULL, NULL);
```

**assistance**

```
CREATE TABLE `asistencia` (
  `codAsistencia` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `mensaje` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pendiente',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `asistencia`
--

INSERT INTO `asistencia` (`codAsistencia`, `fecha`, `mensaje`, `usuario`, `estado`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(10, '2020-11-26 19:54:19', 'eeeee', 17, 'pendiente', NULL, NULL);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `asistencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `asistencia`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codAsistencia`),
  ADD KEY `asistencia_usuario_foreign` (`usuario`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `asistencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `asistencia`
  MODIFY `codAsistencia` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=11;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `asistencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `asistencia`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_asistencia_usuarios` FOREIGN KEY (`usuario`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

**Actuation**

```
CREATE TABLE `actuacion` (
  `codActuacion` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `tiempoEmpleado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mensaje` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `codV3` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `asistencia` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `actuacion`
--

INSERT INTO `actuacion` (`codActuacion`, `fecha`, `tiempoEmpleado`, `mensaje`, `codV3`, `asistencia`) VALUES
(13, '2020-11-26 18:55:11', 12, NULL, NULL, 10),
(14, '2020-11-26 21:02:34', 10, 'rrrr', '555', 10);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `actuacion`
--
ALTER TABLE `actuacion`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codActuacion`),
  ADD KEY `actuacion_asistencia_foreign` (`asistencia`),
  ADD KEY `asistencia` (`asistencia`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `actuacion`
--
ALTER TABLE `actuacion`
  MODIFY `codActuacion` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=15;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `actuacion`
--
ALTER TABLE `actuacion`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_actuacion_asistencia` FOREIGN KEY (`asistencia`) REFERENCES `asistencia` (`codAsistencia`);
COMMIT;
```

i think that i can calculate this time, but i don´t know how to add my other queries to first query

**ADD SCRIPT FIDDLE**

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d2b7ce320ee089b6cdb85770f397843)

Comment: @Akina sorry. i add now

Comment: i was updated.. sorry

Comment: Look [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e100f15c1302c04612254e348c75d529). It contains your codes. The queries output does not match shown ones. Edit this fiddle, make it correct and actual. Then add the reference to edited fiddle into the question text instead of screenshot.

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry @Akina i show all my data and updste my question. Thanks for your response and your time

Comment: @Akina i change all my data, i can execute in fiddle and run ok. I´m sorry for make you lose your time... i hope that you can help me, please